# date picker not working if dropdown with multiselection works and multi selection not working if date picker works

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application i need to have drop down with multi selection along with all in that drop down for doing that i had used the code in the below link

http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Dropdownlist-with-checkboxes-in-asp-net and along with this multi selection i also should have date picker for text boxes for which i had used the code in this link

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DateTimePicker-control-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Example.aspx

the problem is if i have drop down with multi selection date picker is not working and if date picker is working multi selection is not working how can i solve this issue.can anyone help me out

Date picker code

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
<img src="calender.png" />
```

Multi selection code

```
<asp:listbox runat="server" id="lstBoxTest" selectionmode="Multiple">
      <asp:listitem text="Red" value="0"></asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem text="Green" value="1"></asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem text="Yellow" value="2"></asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem text="Blue" value="3"></asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem text="Black" value="4"></asp:listitem>
  </asp:listbox>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
    <link href="sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(<%=lstBoxTest.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #444;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        p, div, ul, li {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>

protected void btnGetSelectedValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string selectedValues = string.Empty;
       foreach (ListItem li in lstBoxTest.Items)
       {
           if (li.Selected == true)
           {
               selectedValues += li.Text + ",";
           }
       }
       Response.Write(selectedValues.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: Post your code please! which you tried, by posting your code the stack overflow committee members will help you.

Comment: i had posted my complete code can you help me out the reason for providing the links instead of code is because we need so many scripts in both of the which could not be downloaded if i post the code

Comment: I think the jquery plugin is conflicting so why date time picker and dropdown box is not working in same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this working example of both datepicker and multiselect as per you want. I have tested in my local

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>asdasd</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/361/Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/361/Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/361/Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: true,
                ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
                daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
    </script>

    <%--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/javascripts/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
    <link href="http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/stylesheets/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(<%=lstBoxTest.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
            });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #444;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        p, div, ul, li {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <img src="calender.png" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBoxTest" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Black" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```